# Getting started with silverlight 3 mvvm

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I've just written my first silverlight 3 app.
It's written using the code behind in a rater messy way.
I want to refactor into mvvm. 
I'm finding it extremely difficult to find any tutorials on this.
So far from what I can gather I'll probably need a mvvm framework. 
Mvvm-light toolkit sounds like it might be what I want, but I can't find a beginners tutorial.
This is actually more frustrating than I thought - do I actually need a framework?
Would I maybe be better just trying to do this from scratch with out a framework?
How did you get started with silverlight and mvvm?
Also I'm using vs2008 so silverlight 4 is a non starter for me.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you start with my session at MIX 2010 "Understanding the MVVM pattern". I go into the MVVM pattern as well as two important components of MVVM Light Toolkit: RelayCommand and Messenger. This should give you a head start.

Then, check the articles on http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted#tutorials

For the records, I am working with a member of the community to produce documentation aimed at beginners, but it takes time, and we do it on our free time.

If you have questions, ask on StackOverflow, but please tag with mvvm-light. I am monitoring this tag and do my best to help people with samples when I can.

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: Thanks for the response, just re read my post and it sound like a rant - wasn't supposed to!
Totally appreciate that you do this in your spare time so thanks!
I'll check out what you suggested.